# SQL Query to insert transpose of a select query into another table

Tags: insert, transpose

I have a table that has a structure with the following data
Table1:

```
DateTime, TagName, Num_Value, Str_Value, Transact_ID
10/8/2016 00:00:00, Batch_Id,NULL,B671,1
10/8/2016 00:00:00, Temperature,70,NULL,1
10/8/2016 00:00:00, Pressure,20,NULL,1
10/8/2016 01:00:00, Batch_Id,NULL,'B672',2
10/8/2016 01:00:00, Temperature,71.6,NULL,2
10/8/2016 01:00:00, Pressure,20.5,NULL,2
```

I would like to write a store procedure that would iterate over these rows and insert one row for all similar transact_id values into a predefined table 'Table2'

Table2:

```
DateTime,BatchID,Temperature,Pressure,Transact_ID
10/8/2016 00:00:00,B671,70,20,1
10/8/2016 01:00:00,B672,71.6,20.5,2
```

I think using sql cursors would be an solution to iterate over table1 and create dynamic sql insert queries. But is there a another more efficient way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic pivot query can generate the table you want:

```
SELECT
    DateTime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TagName = 'Batch_Id'    THEN Str_Value END) AS BatchId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TagName = 'Temperature' THEN Num_Value END) AS Temperature,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TagName = 'Pressure'    THEN Num_Value END) AS Pressure,
    Transact_ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY
    DateTime,
    Transact_ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

The demo is given in MySQL, since you did not mention the exact database you are using, but the query is general and should run on just about any variety of SQL.

Edit: If you want to populate `Table2` using the above query, then just do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (DateTime, BatchID, Temperature, Pressure, Transact_ID)
SELECT ...   -- the query from above
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Can I just write a loop against these results to insert the rows into table 2?

Comment: @P.Paul You don't need a loop.  Just do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you very very much for the prompt response. Works like a charm.